JWT in cookies is undefined
I'm working with JWT and cookies for the first-time. During the login I receive JWT token that I'm trying to save to the jwt to the cookies but for some reason after saving it into the cookies it's telling me that it undefined.
I can see the token in the cookies, but when I'm logging the token into the console in Google Chrome I'm getting undefined as I mentioned. But it works correctly on Safari.
// Debugging: Print the token
        console.log('Received token:', data.token); <---- I can see the token here
    
        // Save token to cookies
        Cookies.set('jwt', data.token, {
          expires: 7,
          path: '/',
          secure: true,
          sameSite: 'Lax', // Set SameSite attribute to Lax for testing
        });
    
        // Debugging: check if the token is set correctly
        const cookieToken = Cookies.get('jwt');
        console.log('Token set in cookies:', cookieToken); <--- here I can`t

This is my whole code:
Login.js:
try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://MYWEBSITE/api/v1/users/login',
        {
          email: formData.email,
          password: formData.password,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          withCredentials: true, // Added withCredentials setting
        }
      );
    
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = response.data;
        console.log('Login successful.');
        setFormData({
          email: '',
          password: '',
        });
    
        // Debugging: Print the token
        console.log('Received token:', data.token);
    
        // Save token to cookies
        Cookies.set('jwt', data.token, {
          expires: 7,
          path: '/',
          secure: true,
          sameSite: 'Lax', // Set SameSite attribute to Lax for testing
        });
    
        // Debugging: check if the token is set correctly
        const cookieToken = Cookies.get('jwt');
        console.log('Token set in cookies:', cookieToken);
    
        // Verify token
        const isValidToken = await checkToken(cookieToken);
    
        if (isValidToken) {
          console.log('Token is valid, navigating to homepage.');
          navigate('/'); // Redirect after successful login
        } else {
          console.error('Invalid token after login.');
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Error logging in:', response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Axios error:', error);
    }

auth.js:
import axios from 'axios';

export const checkToken = async (jwt) => {
  console.log('Token being checked:', jwt); // Debugging

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://MYWEBSITE/api/v1/users/checkToken',
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        },
      }
    );

    
    return response.data.status === 'success';
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      'Error checking token:',
      error.response || error.message || error
    );
    return false;
  }
};

I'm trying to save the JWT into the cookies and then send it in the authorization to the react guard and redirect to the home page.

What is Cookies? I assumed it's a built-in, but it's undefined on my machine. Is it some kind of a library? Does it, by any chance, work asynchronously (just like setters from useState)?

first you should organize better your code:
create a file that handle cokies and inside it you can do:
export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  Cookies.set(AUTH_TOKEN_COOKIE, token, { expires: 7 }); // The token will expire in 7 days
};

import that file in the login component :
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Example login API call
    const response = await fetch('https://your-api-url.com/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      setAuthToken(data.token); // Save JWT in a cookie
      // Redirect or update UI as needed
    } else {
      // Handle login error
      console.error('Login failed');
    }
  };

